# Creating custom database properties using ADO.NET

Tags: c#, vb.net, ado.net

How do we add and list custom properties using ADO.NET?

I know we can achieve this using DAO.

```
Set prp = db.CreateProperty("StartupForm", dbText, strFormName)
 db.Properties.Append prp
```

The above lines of code creates a property using DAO.

What is the equivalent for ADO.NET?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't one. Most databases are not intended to be used by routinely changing the schema from application code. Usually the schema is fixed and just the rows / values change. You may be able to execute SQL that has the same effect (`ALTER TABLE ... ADD` for example), but that's vendor-specific.